# Is there a way to use static method with dependency injection in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

An example is better than a long explanation:

```
// Backery.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Backery } from './Backery.entity';

@Injectable()
export class BackeryService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Backery)
    private readonly backeryRepository: Repository<Backery>,
  ) {}

  static myStaticMethodToGetPrice() {
    return 1;
  }

  otherMethod() {
    this.backeryRepository.find();
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

```
// Backery.resolver.ts
import { Bakery } from './Bakery.entity';
import { BakeryService } from './Bakery.service';

@Resolver(() => Bakery)
export class BakeryResolver {
  constructor() {}

  @ResolveField('price', () => Number)
  async getPrice(): Promise<number> {
    return BakeryService.myStaticMethodToGetPrice(); // No dependency injection here :(
  }
}
```

How can I replace `BakeryService.myStaticMethodToGetPrice()` to use dependency injection, so I can test things easily for example?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want this to be a static method? In other words why can't you just inject `BakeryService` in your `BakeryResolver` and call the price method on an instance of the service?

Comment: @eol the method does not use `this`, so it feels more natural to make it static as it does not depend on the object instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static methods cannot use dependency injection. This is because the idea of dependency injection (at least to Nest) is to inject instances of the dependencies so that they can be leveraged later.

The code you have is valid, in that it will return the value `1` like the static method says to, but the static method cannot use any of the instance values that are injected. You'll find this kind of logic follows in most other DI frameworks.

Comment: This code is valid, but is it the official recommandation? Or it's better to avoid static method entirely in order to use DI and ease the tesing?

Comment: I like to avoid static **except for ** when it comes to dynamic modules.

Comment: static methods can use DI if you get a reference to your nest app object. It has a "resolve" method that allows you to get any object by type from its DI context

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy way to create static functions that use services from your NestJs DI.

One good example is the use for Domain Events and avoiding polluting your entities' constructors with technical services.

In your main.ts

```
let app: INestApplication;

async function bootstrap() {
  app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  install();
  ...
  ...
}

bootstrap();

export const getInstance = () => {
  return app;
};
```

From any static context within your app:

```
import { getInstance } from '@/main';

static async emmitEvent() {
    let eventEmitter = await getInstance().resolve(EventEmitter2);
    eventEmitter.emit(JSON.stringify(nodeCreateEvent));
}
```

Comment: You haven't really made Dependency injection work with static methods, you've just made the static method reference something that _can_ use dependency injection. And if you were to run this static method from outside the main application, you'll get a runtime error due to the bootstrap method possibly not finishing yet. Along with that, your `main.ts` is now used for more than just starting the server, which starts to violate the single responsibility principle Nest tries to endorse.

Comment: It is not very clear on what exactly the OP wants to accomplish but my answer clearly allows you to access the app context from static method. And yes it may fail if you call it ,for whatever reason, outside the app running context.
As for the single responsibility - we prefer having our entities clean instead of injecting, bunch of things through constructor etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with static property and `@Inject()`

```
import { GeoService } from '../geoservice/geoservice.service';
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';

export class myClass {
    @Inject(GeoService)
    private static geoService: GeoService;

    someMethod() {
        this.geoService...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
// app-context.ts
import { INestApplication, Type } from '@nestjs/common';

export class AppContext {
  static instance: INestApplication;

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  static tryGet<TInput = any, TResult = TInput>(typeOrToken: Type<TInput> | Function | string | symbol): TResult | null {
    if (!AppContext.instance) return null;
    try {
      return AppContext.instance.get(typeOrToken);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

in main.ts:

```
const app = AppContext.instance = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  // ...
});
```

Then you need these decorators:

```
// decorators.ts
export const DEPENDENCY_INJECTION_METADATA = 'self:dependency_injection';

export function StaticInject<T>(type: T): ParameterDecorator {
  return (target: object, _key: string | symbol | undefined, index: number) => {
    let dependencies = Reflect.getMetadata(DEPENDENCY_INJECTION_METADATA, target) || [];
    dependencies = [...dependencies, { index, key, type }];
    Reflect.defineMetadata(DEPENDENCY_INJECTION_METADATA, dependencies, target);
  };
}

export const StaticInjection: MethodDecorator = (target: object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
  const dependencies = Reflect.getMetadata(DEPENDENCY_INJECTION_METADATA, target) || [];
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function(...args: unknown[]) { // do to use arrow function here! we need to keep function context
    if (!AppContext.instance) throw new Error('AppContext is not initialized');
    for (const { index, type } of dependencies) {
      args[index] = AppContext.tryGet(type);
      if (!args[index]) throw new Error(`Dependency injection failed for ${type}`);
    }
    return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
  };
};
```

and finally, in your static method:

```
  @StaticInjection
  static myMethod(otherParams: any, @StaticInject(SomeService) someService?: SomeService) {
    return someService.something(otherParams);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).