# how to use winston logger in nest node in static classes

Tags: node.js, logging, nest, winston, nest-winston

I want to use `winston` logging module in my node application and I am using `nest` framework.

So I installed

```
yarn add nest-winston
yarn add winston
```

and in my `app.module.ts`

```
WinstonModule.forRoot({
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.json(),
  ),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      dirname: process.env.LOG_FILE_PATH,
      filename: 'info.log',
      level: 'info',
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      dirname: process.env.LOG_FILE_PATH,
      filename: 'error.log',
      level: 'error',
    }),
  ],
}),
```

and in my contrller file i can inject like this

```
constructor(@Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: LoggerService) { }
```

and this is working fine.

Now I have `DB` class that is `static` with `static` methods. So there will be no `constructor`. So how can I inject in this case.

And in my `main.ts` there is no class so in that too how can i get the `logger` instance.

Comment: This is dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847961/is-there-a-way-to-use-static-method-with-dependency-injection-in-nestjs
TL;DR: Thats not possible without starting up nest app