# Ii it possible to inject a dependency in a static context using NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, static-methods

Is it possible to inject a dependency in a class so the to static methods in a NestJS project?

If so, how could I do this?

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: We are currently making the database connection inside a guard, which is injected into the controllers. I have the requirement to remove the connection to the database from the control layer of the application. The requirement also says to move the connection to an abstract class containing static methods. One of the static methods of this class is a connect method.

Comment: The goal is to have the power to make the connection from any point of the application, and also within the tests, using this class with static methods.

Database connection parameters are dynamic. These database connection parameters change depending on the organization of the logged in user.

Comment: These parameters come from another injectable that fetches them from MongoDB. So we would need to have access to connection parameters inside the class with static methods.

I currently pass these parameters to the class with static methods inside a guard. But I would like to know if it is possible to do this more transparently, through injection.

Comment: [I think this question will answer the question you have, though probably not in a way you're hoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847961/is-there-a-way-to-use-static-method-with-dependency-injection-in-nestjs/65849803#65849803). In short, no, it's not really possible. The longer version is yes, but it''s super hacky